# How can i pass an object to the click event method on wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, click

I'm creating a button (NOT with xaml since it's a set of buttons which are supposed to be created dynamically according to a certain need and not be there constantly). 
When you want to tell the button what to do you're adding a method to the click event like this:

```
btn.Click += b_ClickMethod;
```

and the b_clickMethod has the following signature:

```
private void b_ClickMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

my question is how (or even if i actually can) pass a certain object as the sender in order to pass information to the method. If this object is already set somewhere else then what does it represent?

Comment: The sender is the button that was clicked. What information are you trying to pass to the event?

Comment: for example an certain int or a string.. just to know how i can pass the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I usually get information from an object to its event handler is using its `DataContext`. If this is an option for you (hard to tell if it is), it's a very easy thing to do. If the `DataContext` of your button is set (you can do this from the code-behind quite easily), you can access it like so:

```
private void b_ClickMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Let's say you're trying to pass a Car-object
    var car = sender.DataContext as Car;

    // Manipulate away.
}
```

The way you set the DataContext is - quite simply:

```
CarViewModel someViewModel = new ViewModel(); // or whatever
Car someCarObject = someViewModel.getSomeCar(); // basically - find the object you would like to send.
btn.DataContext = someCarObject;
```

Hope this helps. As an end-note, you might want to reconsider creating buttons like that. If you only need buttons in certain scenarios, you'll have cleaner code if you simply set those buttons' `Visibility` parameter to `Visibility.Hidden`.

Comment: Seibekk but the number of buttons is also not known in advanced so i can't create them and hid them in advanced.. is there still a way to do it properly?

Comment: You COULD use a `ListBox`, databind the list of buttons that are dynamically created somehow to that list's `ItemsSource` and show and hide each one depending on some state for each button.

I'm not saying it's necessarily a bad thing to create UI elements in the code-behind class of a view (it's perfectly acceptable), so if it's easier for you to create them that way (and you're not a big MVVM evangelist), then do so.

Comment: However, I am sure there is some sort of set of buttons that you choose from. Following the Car-analogy of my answer, you could have a finite amount of actions (like `Drive`, `Turn`, `BurnOut`, `OpenSunroof`). If there is, you could create them all and simply hide the ones you're not using. However, if for some reason this is not the scenario, go with code-behind dynamic creation. It'll just be a bit harder to decode your code for other developers later on. If you gave me a better introduction to your situation, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: at my specific case, I'm creating a small app for a social network and there is an option of receiving mail, which creates a button from each message arrived and this button navigate me to another page. So i can't know how many messages I'll get

Comment: Why would you not simply use a `ListBox` control and use the `OnClick()` event for each `ListBoxItem` to navigate the user to the next view? You can even insert each Button into a ListBoxItem, if so need be.